# Skip weekends Business day tasks NetSuite

Tags: sql, record, netsuite, weekend

Using NetSuite, I am trying to automate the creation of monthly tasks. These tasks will fall on the last day of the month, a day before, and 1,2,3,4,5 days after the last day of the month. But, the tasks can't be due on a weekend, only business days. So if the day falls on a sat or sun the dates have to move up. How can I use my custom record to calculate the next months task dates skipping weekends?  Here is a screenshot of the record - see that 10/4 and 10/5 fall on saturday and sunday, how can I have it skip sat and sunday? I used the sql function option to generate the dates and days of the week.

[image]

Comment: Can you make this screenshot bigger please

Comment: if you click and drag the image up to make a new tab in your browser (this is what i do in chrome) it will open the image up in its own tab bigger

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following formula. Replace custbody_date with your field name. This formula should be set in your 'next month' column.

```
CASE WHEN INSTR(to_char({custbody_date}, 'DAY'),'SATURDAY') != 0 
THEN {custbody_date}+2 
WHEN INSTR(to_char({custbody_date}, 'DAY'),'SUNDAY') != 0 
THEN {custbody_date}+1 ELSE {custbody_date} 
END
```

This should also give you an idea to set the value for 'Next Month Day' (skipping saturday and sunday).