# Calculated due date that excludes weekends?

Tags: netsuite

I'm automating creation of tasks in our CRM in Netsuite. Whenever the tasks are created, they will be due as 2 days from today's date.

I currently have a workflow setup where it does just that. However, I've been asked to exclude weekends from these calculations. (Essentially only if a task is created on a Thursday or Friday)

I found [Skip weekends Business day tasks NetSuite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327342/skip-weekends-business-day-tasks-netsuite), and I modified the code to try and fit my situation.

```
CASE WHEN INSTR(to_char({today}, 'DAY'),'THURSDAY') != 0  
THEN {duedate}+4 
WHEN INSTR(to_char({today}, 'DAY'),'FRIDAY') != 0  
THEN {duedate}+3  ELSE {duedate}+2 END
```

I thought that this would work, now that I have it looking at today's date and ignoring weekends if the task is created on a day of the week that would cause the due date to fall over the weekend.

Currently, the execution of my workflow fails and the logs have the following error:

> Check: Action allowed for execution context null?

I've done quite a bit of troubleshooting and research, but I can't seem to find an easy way to set a due date and ignore weekends. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `{duedate}` in your formula when it sounds like you want to set duedate

e.g.

in a workflow within a set field action you'd be updating duedate with something like:

```
CASE WHEN INSTR(to_char({today}, 'DAY'),'THURSDAY') != 0 THEN {today}+4 
WHEN INSTR(to_char({today}, 'DAY'),'FRIDAY') != 0  THEN {today}+3  
ELSE {today}+2 END
```

Comment: Hmm. I would think this would work. I see the error that I've made. I changed references of {duedate} to {today}, and I'm still getting the same error. I'm wondering if it's because I'm setting the due date not as a condition for a Set Field Value action, but rather "Create Record" and setting the due date under that subset.